# Field name serialization in MongoDB + Spring data

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-data

I am wondering about the possibility of field name serialization in MongoDB using Spring data. What I meant in field name serialization is, let's say I have a field called 'projectName' and I want to store this field name as it is in MongoDB but when it is converted to JSON, I want it to be 'project_name'.

I know that I can do this through MongoConverter, but I am wondering is there an annotation like Gson's @SerializedName so I do not have to do conversions for entire classes just because of field names.

As I mentioned earlier, I am using Spring data to work with MongoDB.

Please note that I am aware about @Field annotation which converts the POJO field name into a custom MongoDB field name which I do not need in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is "when it is converted to JSON"? By whom? Jackson? Then just use Jacksons `@JsonProperty` to customize the rendered field name. Spring Data doesn't play into that actually, as all we care about is the translation between the object and the database representation.

Comment: MongoDB uses its own JSON converter not Jackson's and that converter does not seem to have such thing. I agree with you in terms of Spring data, I just wondered maybe there is a way to do this.